# How can I get the length of an array in awk?

Tags: awk

This command

```
echo "hello world" | awk '{split($0, array, " ")} END{print length(array) }'
```

does not work for me and gives this error message

> awk: line 1: illegal reference to array array

Why?

Comment: Actually, your code works for me and returns 2 as expected.

Comment: It works with `gawk` but not POSIX `awk` or `gawk --posix`.

Answer (score 110, accepted):

When you split an array, the number of elements is returned, so you can say:

```
echo "hello world" | awk '{n=split($0, array, " ")} END{print n }'
# ------------------------^^^--------------------------------^^
```

Output is:

```
2
```

Comment: I have used split() before, but never realized it returned a value!

Comment: @bgStack15  surprise! .. Yep, and what a handy value. Also, I think  you'll find that most functions in awk return some value, probably modeled on `c` language `0` for error or some non-zero value is returned as useful information. Good luck!

Answer (score 44):

Mr. Ventimiglia's function requires a little adjustment to do the work (see the semicolon in for statement):

```
function alen(a, i) {
    for(i in a);
    return i
}
```

But don't work all the cases or times. That is because the manner that awk store and "see" the indexes of the arrays: they are associative and no necessarily contiguous (like C.) So, `i` does not return the "last" element.

To resolve it, you need to count:

```
function alen(a, i, k) {
    k = 0
    for(i in a) k++
    return k
}
```

And, in this manner, take care other index types of "unidimensional" arrays, where the index maybe an string. Please see: http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/unix/sedawk/ch08_04.htm. For "multidimensional" and arbitrary arrays, see http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Walking-Arrays.html#Walking-Arrays.

Answer (score 29):

I don't think the person is asking, "How do I split a string and get the length of the resulting array?"  I think the command they provide is just an example of the situation where it arose.  In particular, I think the person is asking 1) Why does length(array) provoke an error, and 2) How can I get the length of an array in awk?

The answer to the first question is that the length function does not operate on arrays in POSIX standard awk, though it does in GNU awk (gawk) and a few other variations.  The answer to the second question is (if we want a solution that works in all variations of awk) to do a linear scan.

For example, a function like this:

```
function alen (a,     i) {
    for (i in a);
    return i;}
```

**NOTE**:  The second parameter i warrants some explanation.

The way you introduce local variables in awk is as extra function parameters and the convention is to indicate this by adding extra spaces before these parameters.  This is discussed in the GNU Awk manual [here](http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Return-Statement).

Comment: good points. My aim was to answer the original question using the terms of the O.P., ie. `awk '{split($0, array, " ")}...'`, and hence my answer, taken from the use of `split` in the original 'The Awk Programming Language'. Good luck to all.

Comment: Thanks.  I didn't intend for my answer to be so pithy.  I was in a bit of a rush.  Maybe I'll soften it a bit.

Comment: But all this does is return the first index of an array? Also, the order of array iteration is not specified by POSIX.

Comment: _The answer to the second question is (if we want a solution that works in all variations of awk)_ [is] _to do a linear scan_ AND to count and to return the number of elements in the given array: `... { for(i in a) c++; return c }`

Comment: @osvein This bug had been introduced by an unfortunate and uninformed edit of this question. Now, 6 years later, I have reverted the answer to the correct revision.

Comment: Oh well, not really. Revision 4 or 6 of this answer doesn't really return the length of the array but only its random last index.

Comment: @DavidA.Ventimiglia Could you please fix your code to actually do what it promises?

Answer (score 22):

In `gawk` you can use the function `length()`:

```
$ gawk 'BEGIN{a[1]=1; a[2]=2; a[23]=45; print length(a)}'
3

$ gawk 'BEGIN{a[1]=1; a[2]=2; print length(a); a[23]=45; print length(a)}'
2
3
```

From [The GNU Awk user's guide](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/String-Functions.html#String-Functions):

> **With gawk and several other awk implementations, when given an array argument, the `length()` function returns the number of elements in the
>   array**. (c.e.) This is less useful than it might seem at first, as
>   the array is not guaranteed to be indexed from one to the number of
>   elements in it. If --lint is provided on the command line (see
>   Options), gawk warns that passing an array argument is not portable.
>   If --posix is supplied, using an array argument is a fatal error (see
>   Arrays).

Comment: I think most prevailing awks all support this feature, not only gawk. I tried awk on macOS and NetBSD, both work.

Answer (score 18):

Just want to point that:

- Don't need to store the result of the `split` function in order to print it.
- If separator is not supplied for the split, the default `FS` (blank space) will be used.
- The `END` part is *useless* here.

  ```
  echo 'hello world' | awk '{print split($0, a)}'
  ```

Comment: quick note : when `sep` isn't supplied, it's whatever `FS`'s value is at that moment, not necessarily the single blank space one.

Answer (score 2):

sample on MacOSX Lion to show used ports (output can be 192.168.111.130.49704 or ::1.49704) :

```
   netstat -a -n -p tcp | awk '/\.[0-9]+ / {n=split($4,a,"."); print a[n]}'
```

In this sample, that print the last array item of 4th column : "49704"

Answer (score 1):

Try this if you are not using gawk.

```
awk 'BEGIN{test="aaa bbb ccc";a=split(test, ff, " "); print ff[1]; print a; print ff[a]}'
```

Output:

```
aaa
3
ccc
```

8.4.4 Using split() to Create Arrays http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/unix/sedawk/ch08_04.htm

Answer (score 0):

Here's a quick way for me to get length of array, init to zero length if non-existent, but don't overwrite any existing ones or accidentally add extra elements :

```
(g/mawk) 'function arrayinit(ar, x) { for(x in ar) {break}; return length(ar) };
```

The for loop basically has O(1) since it exits upon any existing element, regardless of sort order. My old way used to either test, or split empty string. This way saves the split step since the for loop perhaps that function implicitly.

This also works for pseudo multi-dim array like arr[x,y] or gawk arr[x][y] ones without having to worry whether "x" is a sub-array in the gawk sense.

Answer (score 0):

just use this :

---

```
function lengthA(__, _, ___)
{
    # __| input array
    #   |
    #   |--> # of array indices, including
    #        empty cells and/or
    #        NULL-STRING index => __[""]

    for (_ in __)
        break

    if ( ! (_ = -("\x4" < "x\4")) )
        for (___ in __)_++

    return \
    +_<-_ ? length(__) : (_)
}
```

---

The comparison check ensures only `POSIX` mode use the slow method of counting one at a time. Everyone else leverages the built-in `length()` function.

For a gigantic array I was benchmarking, using slow method took 5 seconds while fast one was just a smidgen over 1 sec, so the difference is substantial enough to warrant the methodology split.

The instant `break` out of `for(...)` loop is to force initialize 1st argument as array, otherwise `length(__)` would typecast into a scalar, and (likely) trigger error messages.

Answer (score -1):

```
echo "hello world" | awk '{lng=split($0, array, " ")} END{print lng) }'
```