# How to print an array in defined order in AWK 3.1.3

Tags: awk

I googled it and find out that after AWK 4.0 we can print an array in defined order by putting PROCINFO["sorted_in"] command right before for loop. For example

```
    PROCINFO["sorted_in"] = "@ind_num_asc"
    for( i in array)
          print i, array[i]
```

In AWK 4.0.2, it works. However, I tried it in AWK 3.1.3 environment, it did not work. Does this early version of AWK do not support this function? How to achieve this goal in AWK 3.1.3?

Comment: check out asort/asorti for sorting an array

Comment: No, non-GNU awks and older versions of gawk do not support this functionality. Clarify "defined order" and "this goal". Are you looking to print an array in a specific order and, if so, what is the order (first in or numerical sort or alphabetical sort or ...)? Alternatively are you looking for a mechanism to define different orders of printing arrays like you show in your example by populating PROCINFO[]?

Answer (score 5):

Just keep a second array `order` with numerical indices and the keys for the first array as the values. You can then iterate through `order` in sequence and look up the values of `array`:

```
for (i = 1; i < length(order); i++) {
  print order[i], array[order[i]]
}
```

When building `order`, you may want to check whether the key is already present in `array`, to prevent the keys of `array` being shown multiple times.

Comment: There is no "length" function in 3.1.3.See Mr. Ventimiglia's function (with my extensión) at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9351902/how-can-i-get-the-length-of-an-array-in-awk/19411381#19411381 or just keep the last index used at the creation of "order".