# Unix. Sort a set of data base on row

Tags: shell, sorting, unix

I have a set of data. I want to sort by the "Name=" row and have the correct set of data below each of the "Name=". Is this possible ? I look into the sort reference but did not find anything with this logistics. The amount of data I get below each "Name=" can be totally different.

I attempted to use man sort to find a tool to solve this but I can not seem to find something like this. Thank you in advance. I may be using the incorrect tool or command.

My set of data currently. I have thousands of rows with similar data.

```
Name=Sally15 
Kitty Up Count 10 Active 1
Trex Up Count 5 Active 1
Name=Bob14
Bird Up Count 10 Active 5
Dog Up Count 2 Active 3 
Trex Up Count 5 Active 1
Name=Sally12 
Cow Up Count 5 Active 1
Trex Up Count 5 Active 2
Name=Bob13 
Cow Up Count 5 Active 1
```

Desire Results

```
Name=Bob13 
Cow Up Count 5 Active 1
Name=Bob14
Bird Up Count 10 Active 5
Dog Up Count 2 Active 3 
Trex Up Count 5 Active 1
Name=Sally12 
Cow Up Count 5 Active 1
Trex Up Count 5 Active 2
Name=Sally15 
Kitty Up Count 10 Active 1
Trex Up Count 5 Active 1
```

What is happening on my server

```
(admin)$ cat file
Name=Sally15
Kitty Up Count 10 Active 1
Trex Up Count 5 Active 1
Name=Bob14
Bird Up Count 10 Active 5
Dog Up Count 2 Active 3
Trex Up Count 5 Active 1
Name=Sally12
Cow Up Count 5 Active 1
Trex Up Count 5 Active 2
Name=Bob13
Cow Up Count 5 Active 1
[admins01:/script/users/admin]
(admin)$ gawk -v RS='Name=' '
    NR>1 {record[$1]=$0}
    END {
        PROCINFO["sorted_in"]="@ind_str_asc"
        for (key in record) printf "%s%s", RS, record[key]
    }
' file
Name=Sally12
Cow Up Count 5 Active 1
Trex Up Count 5 Active 2
Name=Bob13
Cow Up Count 5 Active 1
Name=Sally15
Kitty Up Count 10 Active 1
Trex Up Count 5 Active 1
Name=Bob14
Bird Up Count 10 Active 5
Dog Up Count 2 Active 3
Trex Up Count 5 Active 1
```

Comment: Your input does not match your output for "bob13"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I bet your version of gawk is "old". Try this perl:

```
perl -0777 -ne 'print join "", sort split /^(?=Name=)/m' file
```

---

GNU awk: use "Name=" as the record separator, and sort by the first word of the record.

```
gawk -v RS='Name=' '
    NR>1 {record[$1]=$0} 
    END {
        PROCINFO["sorted_in"]="@ind_str_asc"
        for (key in record) printf "%s%s", RS, record[key]
    }
' file
```

Note that this will use lexicographical sorting, so "Bob10" will sort **between** "Bob1" and "Bob2"

Test:

```
$ cat file
Name=Sally15 
Kitty Up Count 10 Active 1
Trex Up Count 5 Active 1
Name=Bob14
Bird Up Count 10 Active 5
Dog Up Count 2 Active 3 
Trex Up Count 5 Active 1
Name=Sally12 
Cow Up Count 5 Active 1
Trex Up Count 5 Active 2
Name=Bob13 
Cow Up Count 5 Active 1

$ gawk -v RS='Name=' '
      NR>1 {record[$1]=$0} 
      END {
          PROCINFO["sorted_in"]="@ind_str_asc"
          for (key in record) printf "%s%s", RS, record[key]
      }
  ' file 
Name=Bob13 
Cow Up Count 5 Active 1
Name=Bob14
Bird Up Count 10 Active 5
Dog Up Count 2 Active 3 
Trex Up Count 5 Active 1
Name=Sally12 
Cow Up Count 5 Active 1
Trex Up Count 5 Active 2
Name=Sally15 
Kitty Up Count 10 Active 1
Trex Up Count 5 Active 1
```

Comment: If the name changes to say Sally , Mary , John and etc how can I include this ?

Comment: Include it how? My answer does not rely on the name at all.

Comment: Name=Sally14
Bird Up Count 10 Active 5
Dog Up Count 2 Active 3
Trex Up Count 5 Active 1
Name=Bob13
Cow Up Count 5 Active 1
Name=Bob15
Kitty Up Count 10 Active 1
Trex Up Count 5 Active 1
Name=Sally12
Cow Up Count 5 Active 1
Trex Up Count 5 Active 2

Comment: ^ for example if the name is not Bob but it's Sally. The solution seems to not work. lexicographical sorting is what I should be looking up correct ? Thank you.

Comment: what output do you want?

Comment: I see your edit. My code produces your desired ordering.

Comment: Hello Glenn. I updated my "Desire Result" and table to show you what I mean. If Bob is a different name (ex Sally, James, Kevin) with different numbers and I use your solution it does not work. Still that solution is great and I will be using it for other purposes.

Comment: What does "does not work" mean? what output do you get?

Comment: Hi glenn. I edit it to show you what's going on when I use the script. It looks like it's wasn't sorting correcting ex. Bob13 , Bob15 , Sally12 , Sally14.

Comment: `PROCINFO["sorted_on"]` only works if you're using a version of gawk earlier than 4.0.0. If you're using a version older than that it'll be silently ignored and the sort order won't change. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16075582/how-to-print-an-array-in-defined-order-in-awk-3-1-3

Comment: True scholar Glenn. Working as intended. Answer Accepted.